# How to display badges in live tile for windows UAP using NotificationsExtensions.Win10 package?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uap

I am creating a Windows 10 application. I need to display badges in live tile. I installed NotificationsExtensions.Win10 Nuget package.I use the following code.

```
  public static void UpdateTileBadgeNumberUsingNotificationExtensions()
    {
        BadgeNumericNotificationContent badgeContent = new BadgeNumericNotificationContent(2);
        BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(badgeContent.CreateNotification());
    }
```

Here CreateNotification method is not available on badgeContent.How can I implement badge count using NotificationsExtensions.Win10 Nuget package.

Comment: Below code gives this exception : Value does not fall within the expected range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your code as follows:

```
 BadgeNumericNotificationContent badgeContent = new BadgeNumericNotificationContent(2);
 BadgeNotification bnotification = new BadgeNotification(badgeContent.GetXml());
 BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(bnotification);
```

After you have created a new `BadgeNumericNotificationContent` instance, you just got a content. You need to call `GetXml()` from this content and set the xml document to a `BadgeNotification` instance. Then you can update the badge by the `BadgeNotification`.

Comment: I have to show badge only to large,medium and wide tile and not in small tile.Ho can this be possible?

Comment: @subminer  I think it is impossible. If you want know more details or want some workarounds you can open a new thread about this new question, and describe more things about your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var badge = new BadgeNumericNotificationContent(2);
        XmlDocument bdoc = content.GetXml();
        BadgeNotification bnotification = new BadgeNotification(bdoc); 
        BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(bnotification);
```

Comment: I have to show badge only to large,medium and wide tile and not in small tile.How can this be possible?

Comment: How we can animate live tiles?